# How to solve $\log_{3x-1}(1-x^4)-\log_{3x-1}(x+x^3)\leq \log_{3x-1}(\frac{3}{2})$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

$$\log_{3x-1}(1-x^4)-\log_{3x-1}(x+x^3)\leq \log_{3x-1}(\frac{3}{2})$$
So the function is defined where: $\log_a(x)$, $a> 0$ and $x> 0$
$$\log_{3x-1}(\frac{1-x^4}{x+x^3})\leq \log_{3x-1}(\frac{3}{2})$$

My question is about the last expression, how does rising function vs lowering function impact inequality.

Comment: don't you just do the obvious thing of $(3x-1)$ to the power of both sides? I tried this, and found a root of the quartic by inspection...

Comment: Yep. Just found the other root. So now I have fully factorised the quartic...

Comment: Ok solved. Anyway, what do you mean by "rising function vs lowering function"?

Comment: @AdamRubinson I might not know the right terminology, but the function, that if you look at the graph when $x\rightarrow ..$, goes up is "rising", and if it goes down it is "falling"

Comment: Which function are you referring to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have
$$\log_{3x-1}(\frac{1-x^4}{x+x^3})\leq \log_{3x-1}(\frac{3}{2})$$
or,
$$\frac{\ln(\frac{1-x^4}{x+x^3})}{\ln(3x-1)}\leq \frac{\ln(\frac{3}{2})}{\ln(3x-1)}.$$
Multiply both sides by $\ln(3x-1)$, to obtain
$$\ln(\frac{1-x^4}{x+x^3})\leq \ln(\frac{3}{2})\qquad\text{if }\ln(3x-1)>0$$
and
$$\ln(\frac{1-x^4}{x+x^3})\geq \ln(\frac{3}{2})\qquad\text{if }\ln(3x-1)<0.$$
So to begin with, we of course need $3x-1>0$, but also $3x-1\ne 1$.
As $\ln$ is increasing, we arrive at
$$\left(\frac{1-x^4}{x+x^3} \leq \frac{3}{2}\;\land\; x>\frac43\right)
\;\lor\; \left(\frac{1-x^4}{x+x^3} \geq \frac{3}{2}\;\land\; \frac13<x<\frac43\right).$$

Meanwhile, it is overdue to simplify some of the fractions: $$\frac{1-x^4}{x+x^3}=\frac{(1-x^2)(1+x^2)}{x(1+x^2)}=\frac{1-x^2}x.$$

Comment: Shouldn't it be $\frac{2}{3}$ instead of $\frac{4}{3}$ in your solution?

Comment: This answer is much more correct than my answer. And I agree with you Bili - it should be 2/3 not 4/3.

Comment: The answer I got is: { $x: \frac{1}{3} < x \leq \frac{1}{2}$} U { $x: x > \frac{4}{3} $}